# Python: Code to test Goldbach Conjecture for 1st 10000 numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am a Maths student currently studying a module called Computational Mathematics. As part of an assignment, I have to investigate Goldbach's conjecture for the first 10,000 numbers, in Python. I have used the sieve of Eratosthenes to obtain the prime numbers up to 10000 (excluding 1 and 2):

```
def sieve(highest_prime):
    primes=list(range(2,highest_prime+1))
    for i in primes:
        j=2
        while i*j<=primes[-1]:
            if i*j in primes:
                primes.remove(i*j)
            j=j+1
        return primes
N_primes=sieve(10000)
del N_primes[0]
```

I have also obtained a list of even numbers up to 100000 (excluding 2 and 4):
**even_numbers=list(range(6,10001,2))**
I now need a code to test whether all the integers in "even_numbers" can be expressed as the sum of two numbers from N_primes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

For each even number, you can check if it satisfies Goldbach's conjecture by iterating through the primes up to n/2 and checking if subtracting the prime from the even number results in a prime number.

Example code:

```
for n in even_numbers:
    found = False
    for i in primes:
        if (n - i) in primes:
            print(n,':',i, (n-i))
            found = True
            break
        if i >= n/2:
            break
    if not found:
        raise Exception("You have disproven Goldbach's conjecture: %d is the exception." % n)
```